# why i got an error while running C:\otp\otp>bin\start-server.bat in command prompt?

Tags: http

When i'm tring to run Open trip planner in my windos system i got an error like this why this happens?

when i'm tring to run 
C:\otp\otp>bin\start-server.bat
in command prompt,i had an error like below..
can anyone know why this happens??

C:\otp\otp>bin\start-server.bat

```
C:\otp\otp>java -Xmx1448m -jar lib\winstone.jar --webappsDir=webapps
 .......
 .......
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:47:59] - Beginning extraction from war file
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - No webapp classes folder found - C:\otp\otp\web
apps\opentripplanner-webapp\WEB-INF\classes
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - Deployed web application found at opentripplann
er-webapp.war
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: contro
lPort=disabled
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - Error during HTTP listener init or shutdown
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HttpListener.getServerSocket(HttpListener.java:102)
        at winstone.HttpListener.run(HttpListener.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - HTTP Listener shutdown successfully
[Winstone 2012/11/22 15:48:00] - AJP13 Listener started: port=8009
```

Comment: I believe `>` is not a valid character in a directory name on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you why:

> Error during HTTP listener init or shutdown
>
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

The port the application tries to bind to, is already in use by another application. Change the port or shutdown the other application.

Comment: thanks Cynical and CodeCasterfor ur reply ,but when i run
C:\Users\Riyas Sulthan>netstat -a
i cant find out which application is already listing..
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           RiyasSulthan:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           RiyasSulthan:0         LISTENING

Comment: also in brower http://localhost:8080/opentripplanner-webapp/index.html will generate HTTP error:404, not found

Comment: Use `netstat -b` to see the binary that is bound to the port. The 404 is from another webserver that is running on your machine.

Comment: when i tried netstat -b it says that the requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: @anisha then [start an elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/).

Answer (score 1):

`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`... Seems you have something that is already listening on the port you have specified. You have to check what is using it (especially if it's a standard one like 80 or 443).

Comment: i cant find out which one is listening..TCP    [::]:80                RiyasSulthan:0         LISTENING

Comment: You mean that you know which port you want your server to bind, but you can't find out who is using it? Or you don't know the port at all?

Comment: i know that i want my server to bind to port 8080. Also in brower "localhost:8080/opentripplanner-webapp/index.html" will generate HTTP error:404, not found

Comment: sir i'm trying to run open trip planner using my gtfs

Comment: Since your server is not running, the URL will always get a 404. Try using `localhost:8080` and see who is listening there. Another approach would be to bind to a different port.

Comment: By using localhost:8080,Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

    /javadoc ---> org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context@e1cfa7{/javadoc,file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.2/javadoc}
    /geoserver ---> org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@10811b5{/geoserver,file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.2/webapps/geoserver/}

Comment: Sounds like you have a Jetty instance which is running on port 8080. Try to stop that or to run your program on a different port.